# How to map a list using Automapper and Moq?

Tags: c#, mocking

How do I configure mock to return a list as a result from another list?

I tried the code below without success.

```
mock.GetMock<ICustomerRepository>().Setup(c=> c.GetListCustomers()).Return(listCustomersDTO);
```

Comment: Looks ok to me. You mention Automapper. Is listCustomersDTO something that you want to return not in the state you have it but after mapped?

Comment: That's right, I have a list that I have prepared for you to return.